# DTM increment prop for other report suit

Tags: adobe, adobe-analytics

We have a `Direct Call Rule` in a `report suite`. Among other stuff, it is supposed to track a variable belonging to another `report suite`.

Is there a special function which allows something like:

`_doStuff(reportSuite, prop,...)`

I was intending to place it inside the `Sequential Javascript` in the `Third Party Tags`.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for [s.sa()](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/function_sa.html)

Comment: Crayon, thanks, it is exactly what I need.